# Prestashop: new domain still pointing to old url and unable to access back-end

Tags: prestashop

I am in the process of cloning my shop ahead of a much dreaded prestashop upgrade ([best practice here](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/271082-upgrade-tips/)). My shop is up and running in a subfolder of my root (/.) dir (ex: `mydomain.com/shop/`).

I followed all the instructions given, namely:

- Created a new folder in my root (/.) directory -> `/newfolder/`
- Exported prestashop database to my hard drive
- Copied all my prestashop files to my hard drive (using FTP)
- Created new database and imported the local back-up
- Uploaded all my files from hard drive to new folder
- Updated my `config/settings.inc.php` with new database credentials
- (Also updated `config/settings.inc.old.php` and `config/settings.old.php` just in case)
- Updated the `physical_uri` field of my `ps_shop_url` table to `/newfolder/`
- Didn't edit the `DOMAIN` and `SSL_DOMAIN` fields of `ps_configuration` because domain remained unchanged (ex: `mydomain.com`)
- Even removed all files from `cache/smarty/cache` and `cache/smarty/compile` except the `index.php`
- Removed `newfolder/.htaccess`
- Cleared my browser cookies and cache (multiple times)

At this point I tried to connect to my new domain (ex: `mydomain.com/newfolder`) and I was redirected to my old url (ex: `mydomain.com/shop`).

I then tried to access the back-office of my new shop (ex: `mydomain.com/newfolder/admin1`) and when I input my credential I get redirected to the exact same log-in page with no error message whatsoever.

What am I missing guys ?
Any help appreciated,
Thanks !
C

btw:

- version of Prestashop (for both folders) is 1.6.0.14
- site is hosted on 1and1 servers
- db are mysql 5.1 for current shop, 5.5 for clone shop

EDIT #1 :
Here is my `newfolder/.htaccess` :

`Options +FollowSymLinks

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>


# Disable Multiviews
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: lademo.fr
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/shop/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Etag
</IfModule>
FileETag none
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf application/x-font-ttf font/otf application/x-font-otf font/opentype
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /shop/index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Comment: Why did you removed your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre (sorry misread that initially) - I removed it since as per the info I collected online, it is generated by prestashop and referenced my old url. Still have a local copy though, will try to add it back via FTP.
Why shouldn't I have deleted it ?

Comment: You need to keep it in place. Go to `mydomain.com/newfolder/admin1` and to `SEO & URL` page. There you can configure your new shop path. After saving this page, Prestashop will regenerate the `.htaccess` file. You might have to save this page 2 times in order for the `.htaccess` file to be rewritted (a known bug)

Comment: Yes, problem is I can't connect to my back-office either: whenever I do I'm stuck in a loop (cf infra)... No way to trigger the .htaccess rewrite otherwise?

Comment: Well, edit your question and post your `.htaccess` file. I will edit it for you.

Comment: You should note that the best practices you linked in your question asked you to create a new sudbomain (ie: test.domain.com instead of www.domain.com/test).

Comment: Just edited the post with my .htaccess (it does indeed reference my old url)
Re: subdomain, I did create it (shop.mydomain.com) just haven't linked it to the folder yet, could that be the problem ? Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Yep, it will be easier by linking your subdomain directly to your folder in 1and1 virtualhost config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110353/discussion-between-clecai-and-florian-lemaitre).